# javascript array push not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

This is my jS code.  When I press the button I want to add another element with a value of 1.  Right now it is resetting the the array so I never get more than one element.  What do I do here?

```
 var x = document.getElementsByTagName('button');//return button array
 var age_array = [];
  smoker_array = [];
  relation_array = [];

  age = 0;

//add button clicked
x[0].addEventListener("click", function(){

   /*
   var age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value;//pull age from box
   var relation = document.getElementsByName("rel")[0].value;//pull relation
   let smoker = document.querySelector('[name=smoker').checked;

   //check relation 
   if(relation === "")
   {
       alert("please select a realation"); 
   }

   //check to see if age < 0
   if(age < 0 || age === " ")
   {
       alert("age not applicable");
   }
    */


  age_array.push(1);
  alert(age_array.length);


});

/*function submit(age, relation, smoker)
{
   age_array.push(age);

    alert(age_array[0]);
    alert(age_array[1]);
    /*
    x[1].addEventListener("click", function(){
       var age = JSON.stringify(entry_age);
       alert(entry_age[1]);
       document.getElementbyClassName("debug").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(entry_relation);
       document.getElementByClass("debug").innerHTML = JSON.stringfy(entry_smoker);  
    });
}
    */
```

here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Household builder</title>
        <style>
            .debug {
                font-family: monospace;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 10px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Household builder</h1>
        <div class="builder">
            <ol class="household"></ol>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Age
                        <input type="text" name="age">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Relationship
                        <select name="rel">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                            <option value="self">Self</option>
                            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                            <option value="child">Child</option>
                            <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                            <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Smoker?
                        <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="add">add</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <pre class="debug"></pre>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code as shown will not reset the array - perhaps you've trimmed too much of your actual code to show what you are doing wrong

Comment: does the alert pop up even if it is wrong? if not, you are probably trying to assign a handler to an element that has not loaded yet.

Comment: One reason to post your code as a runnable snippet is to see if it does what you say it does. ;-) Voting to close as "can't reproduce".

Comment: I can't get it to run hence why I'm posting

Comment: What happens? What's in the console?

Comment: It'll only show store the first value.  I'm doing an alert(element[0]) and it'll display the value of that element but it'll show alert(element[1]) as undefined, each time you click the button it'll rewrite the array and you'll only have one element which is element[0]

Comment: Each time i click the button it increments... seems like its running properly

Comment: It running on this machine but not in netbeans

Comment: *"Array push not working"* - You're not pushing, you're unshifting. But anyway, as already mentioned the code shown works.

Comment: I just posted an edit to the code the way it is in the full file is not working

Comment: Regarding the edit, why is most of the code commented out? Even including the comments there doesn't seem to be anything there that could reset the `age_array`. Even if you uncommented that stuff, nothing shown calls the `submit()` function, so how is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the reason, but your code won't work in *strict mode*.

```
var age_array = [];
    smoker_array = [];
    relation_array = [];
```

should be:

```
var age_array = [],
    smoker_array = [],
    relation_array = [];
```

or:

```
var age_array = [];
var smoker_array = [];
var relation_array = [];
```

Comment: same for ```var age = 0;```. When you say it *doesn't work*, what happen? Can you see the alert or it looks like nothing happens at all. If so, feel free to wrap you code into a ```try { ... } catch(e) { alert(e.toString()); }``` - or equivalent.

Comment: Even if it were in strict mode, that would result in an error, not the behaviour described in the question.

Comment: @MasonWhite maybe your page is reloading. That would explain the loss of data. What if you put another ```alert()``` before the ```addEventListener```.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for the help.  There seems to be something wrong with the HTML.  I don't know what.  I got the JS working using my own HTML, and I'm not allowed to change the HTML.  Anyway thanks for all y'all help.

Marking this as answered